# how do we log into a Salesforce cloned sandbox?

Tags: salesfoce, sandbox-clone

i have cloned an existing sandbox in salesforce. the email id of the sandbox has been updated with .invalid. now when i try to log into the sandbox the verification code is being send to the email id with .invalid appended.

how do i edit the email id without logging in?

Comment: what is the name of your sandbox?

Comment: cmask_target@infa.com.graphnew

Answer (score 4):

Whichever user originally created the Sandbox will have a valid email in the sandbox.  Try to login as that user and the verification code will go to their real email address.

**UPDATE**

As @Sebastian Kessel commented, once you've logged into the Sandbox as that user, you can go to the Users list view in setup and edit other users' email addresses to be their real email address.

Comment: You should add that the user in question can also fix Other users’ emails.